# This setup requires .NET Framework version 4.5

Tags: c#, .net, windows, installation

I have migrated a project from .NET Framework 4 to .Net Framework 4.5. When I create the setup project, and run the installer, i get the error message "This setup requires .NET Framework version 4.5". This is the version used in each project and it is installed on my local machine.

How can this problem be solved?

Answer (score 0):

If you use Visual Studio :
Select Project -> Properties -> publish -> required components

and make sure Net Framework 4.5 is selected

Comment: It is selected.I have also made sure that every project in the solution is using .NET Framework 4.5.

Comment: which version of visual studio are you using ? If you use Visual Studio 2010 it can´t work. U have to use Visual studio 2012 minimum